# Searching in array by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search in elasticsearch but getting hit even though the condition does not match.
For eg:-

```
     {
         tweet: [
              {
                  firstname: Lav
                  lastname: byebye
             }
             {
                   firstname: pointto
                   lastname: ihadcre
             }
             {
                   firstname: letssearch
                   lastname: sarabhai
             }
          ]
      }
    }
```

Now there are following condition:-

1)
    must:-   firstname: Lav
    must:-   lastname: byebye
required:there should be hit

getting: Hit

2)
    must:-   firstname: Lav
    must:-   lastname: ihadcre
required:there should not be hit

getting: Hit

I should not be getting hit in 2nd condition which is problem

thanks for help

Comment: can u describe the exact query that you have tried out?

Answer (score 4):

To achieve the behavior that you are describing, tweets should be indexed as [nested objects](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/) and searched using [nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query/) or [filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-filter/). For example:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/test-idx
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_shards": 1,
        "index.number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "tweet": {"type": "nested"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/1" -d '{
    "tweet": [{
        "firstname": "Lav",
        "lastname": "byebye"
    }, {
        "firstname": "pointto",
        "lastname": "ihadcre"
    }, {
        "firstname": "letssearch",
        "lastname": "sarabhai"
    }]
}
'
echo
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/test-idx/_refresh"
echo
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "tweet",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.firstname" : "Lav"}
                        },
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.lastname" : "byebye"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "tweet",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.firstname" : "Lav"}
                        },
                        {
                            "match" : {"tweet.lastname" : "ihadcre"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: It's not just at using nested queries at query-time. Make sure to change your mapping to support nesting at index-time too. Read [the es docs on nested mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/)

Comment: I hope the example will help you to figure it out.